# Find a partition of the natural numbers satisfying the following

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each of the following statements, find a partition of $\mathbb N$ satisfying the stated requirement:

1. All the sets in the partition have exactly two elements
2. There are exactly three sets in the partition
3. There are infinitely many sets in the partition and each set in the partition has infinitely many elements

For the first one, my partition will be constructed as follows: $X_1=\{1,2\}, X_2=\{3,4\}, X_3=\{5,6\}$... etc.

For the second: $X_1=\{1\}, X_2=\{3,5,7,9,11..etc.\}, X_3=\{2,4,6,8,10..etc.\}.$

For the third one, however, I am just not sure how I am supposed to construct such a partition. I am thinking of basing the sets on the prime numbers somehow (each set being the set of the multiples of a prime without overlap) but I am not sure how that would work

Comment: No, I must have not been clear. A different partition for each one of them.

Comment: Hi KelKel23 and welcome to MSE! Thank you for providing context and your work on your question. As a reminder, please remember to upvote answers you find helpful and accept the one answer which best answers your question once you have found a satisfactory resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the third one let $X_1 = \{1\}\cup\{n\in\Bbb N : n= 2k\}$ and $X_1=\{n\in\Bbb N\setminus X_1 : n = 3k\}$ and inductively, $X_j = \{n\in\Bbb N\setminus X_{j-1}: x=p_jk\}$ with $p_j$ the $j^{th}$ prime.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. I had (kind of) the right idea, but I just couldn't formalize it. Do my answers for the other two look correct, though? Is there a better way to write them?

Comment: @KelKel23 yep, good on you!

Answer (score 2):

$1$

$2 \quad \;\;\;3$

$4 \quad\;\;\; 5 \quad\;\;\; 6$

$7 \quad \;\;\; 8 \quad\;\;\; 9 \quad 10$

$11\quad 12\quad \;13\quad 14\quad 15$

ET CETERA.

Let each set of the partition be the members of a column in the pattern above.